# Multi level Paging - OS

Tags: operating-system, paging, memory-address, page-tables

One statement from the book:

Second level page tables should have a maximum size such that they each can fit in a single page frame

What does this mean?

Comment: I think what the text should have been: "Second level page table **entries** should have a maximum size such that they each can fit in a single page frame."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are pontificating that a second level page table should fit in a single page frame. This is rather nonsensical, however, particularly because some systems have variable page sizes. They are guessing at how some particular MMU's caching works and how the system handles paging of tables (if is allowed at all).

Operating systems textbooks are notoriously bad and have you take what they say with a grain of salt.